# CSS background does not show up when doing no-repeat

Tags: css

I have written the following css style, **it does not work**... And I'm Clueless why?!

```
td.PostiveNumber
{
color:Green;
background-image:url(images/1354052077_arrow_large_up.png) no-repeat left !important;
text-align:right;
z-index:100;
}
```

I tried this to and it worked, so I thought to myself it's only to set no-reapeat on and position the picture.

**THIS WORKS, but looks buttugly...** :(

```
{
color:Green;
background-image:url(images/1354052077_arrow_large_up.png);
text-align:right;
z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Applying a z-index to a TD makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `background-image` CSS property should only be used to define the url of the image used.

`no-repeat` belongs to the `background-repeat` property, and `left` corresponts to `background-position`. `background` groups all of those, so:

change `background-image:` to `background:`, or split it up:

```
background-image:url(images/1354052077_arrow_large_up.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left;
```

Comment: background-image doesn't support those extra parameters, you can also use: background-repeat & background-position.

Answer (score 1):

You have two way:

one :

```
background-image:url(images/1354052077_arrow_large_up.png) no-repeat left !important;
```

change to :

```
background:url(images/1354052077_arrow_large_up.png) no-repeat left !important;
```

or

use this way :

```
    background-image:url(images/1354052077_arrow_large_up.png) ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat ;
    background-position: left;
```